# App crashes on Login button click in php connection and mysql connection

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am trying to create a login activity where I verify and check if the values is correct and not null please help me ... where I click the login button with the following codes my app crashes. please help me thanks in advance.
I am new to android studio programming please be patient with me thanks

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.map.laurence.dbtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText user,pass;
    Button login,register;

    String loginUrl = "http://192.168.56.1/login.php";
    RequestQueue requestQueue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "You clicked insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            System.out.println(response.toString());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            parameters.put("user", user.getText().toString());

                            return parameters;
                        }
                    };
                    requestQueue.add(request);


                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                            loginUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            System.out.println(response.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "You clicked Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            try {
                                JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("user");

                                for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String user = student.getString("username");
                                    String password = student.getString("password");
                                    String access = student.getString("access");
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        if (password == pass.toString()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }


                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "its null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }


                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            System.out.append(error.getMessage());

                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

            }


        });

    }

}
```

Layout file **login.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.map.laurence.dbtest.Login">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:id="@+id/user"
                android:hint="Username"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:id="@+id/pass"
                android:hint="Password"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:text="LOGIN"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:text="REGISTER"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';
    loginStudent();

}

function loginStudent()
{
    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];


    global $connect;
    $query = "select * from user where username='$user';";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0 ){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $temp_array[] = $row;

        }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("students"=>$temp_array));
mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

**This is my error on my LogCat**

> 08-29 12:16:39.731 3460-3460/com.map.laurence.dbtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.map.laurence.dbtest, PID: 3460
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                  at com.map.laurence.dbtest.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:72)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: put your Logcat.

Comment: just updated it with the error sir

Comment: i think you forgot to initialize your requestQueue parameter.

Comment: should i treat it as a string value?

Answer (score 1):

```
 requestQueue.add(request);
```

This Line is responsible for NullPointerException.
You are calling requestQueue.add(request) method on null object.

First Initialize requestQueue object like below sample code.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
```